# Add "first" and "last" classes to strings containing one or more <p> tags in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, append, domdocument, prepend

I have two strings I'm outputting to a page

```
# string 1
<p>paragraph1</p>

# string 2
<p>paragraph1</p>
<p>paragraph2</p>
<p>paragraph3</p>
```

What I'd like to do is turn them into this

```
# string 1
<p class="first last">paragraph1</p>

# string 2
<p class="first">paragraph1</p>
<p>paragraph2</p>
<p class="last">paragraph3</p>
```

I'm essentially trying to replicate the css equivalent of `first-child` and `last-child`, but I have to physically add them to the tags as I cannot use CSS. The strings are part of a MPDF document and nth-child is not supported on `<p>` tags.

I can iterate through the strings easy enough to split the `<p>` tags into an array

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$question_paragraphs = array();
$dom->loadHTML($q['quiz_question']);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $node)
{
 $question_paragraphs[] = $dom->saveHTML($node);
}
```

But once I have that array I'm struggling to find a nice clean way to append and prepend the `first` and `last` class to either end of the array. I end up with lots of ugly loops and array splicing that feels very messy.

I'm wondering if anyone has any slick ways to do this? Thank you :)

Edit Note: The two strings are outputting within a `while(array)` loop as they're stored in a database.

Comment: Is this  the logic? The first node gets `first last`, the second node gets `first`, and the last node gets `last`?

Comment: @Barmar The first and last <p> always get those classes, if there is only 1 <p> tag then it get's both the first and last class, if there are multiple <p> tags then the first and last get them. Alternatively, I'd be happy with a class="single" if there is only 1 <p> tag, and then a first/last if there is >1. Both would be fine.

Comment: So your `string 1` and `string 2` aren't in the same document?

Comment: @Barmar Same document, string 1 and string 2 are in the same loop outputting from a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index the node list with the `item()` method, so you can add the attribute to the first and last elements in the list.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$question_paragraphs = array();
$dom->loadHTML($q['quiz_question']);
$par = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
if ($par->length == 1) {
    $par->item(0)->setAttribute("class", "first last");
} elseif ($par->length > 1) {
    $par->item(0)->setAttribute("class", "first");
    $par->item($par->length - 1)->setAttribute("class", "last");
}
    
foreach($par as $node)
{
    $question_paragraphs[] = $dom->saveHTML($node);
}
```